# Spring Roo DBRE JDBC driver not available for 'org.postgresql.Driver'

Tags: java, spring-roo

Im using postgres in Spring Roo and when I tried to use DBRE when installing

```
database introspect --schema no-schema-required
```

the response was

```
addon search --requiresDescription "#jdbcdriver,driverclass:org.postgresql.Driver" found no matches
JDBC driver not available for 'org.postgresql.Driver'
```

even manually search through

```
addon search --requiresDescription "#jdbcdriver,driverclass:org.postgresql.Driver"
```

result was

```
0 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.2 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
```

Im using STS 3.1 and I have internet connection.

I have tried this before and it worked.
what could have happened?

Comment: I think they are currently updating the repo or something... let me try after few hours...

Comment: If you experience this just manually install the drivers... it seems at that time the repo is updating...